# get one record for each group sorted by some column

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
id, country,  name, age
 1,  Italy,  Burke,  21
 2,  Italy, Yefrem,  20
 3,  Spain, Valter,  30
 4,  Spain,    Max,  11
```

How can i get one oldest citizen for each country
For example result should contain only rows `1` and `3`

Result should be grouped by country and in each group entry with highest age should be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an inline view to filter the rows and then a join to the table itself to get all the columns back like so:

```
select t.id, t.country, t.name, t.age
from test t
join (
  select max(age) as age, country
  from test
  group by country
) s
on t.age = s.age and t.country = s.country;
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2523ce/3